# json to xml transformation using json-to-xml() funtion produces output in undesirable format

Tags: java, json, xml, xslt, saxon

I have xsl file that I am trying to apply  xsl template to sample json. Instead of producing valid xml document with json key and values, it producers ill formed xml with encoded strings. 
Below is the command I run with.

```
java -cp /Users/vn04pa5/.m2/repository/net/sf/saxon/Saxon-HE/9.9.1-1/Saxon-HE-9.9.1-1.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:"initial-template" -xsl:"XBorderPOJSON.xsl" input='{
  "purchaseOrderNo": "yvueBluWlI",
  "sourceMarketOrderNo": "ZONWqmCorD",
  "destinationMarketOrderNo": "xFildoWLxd"}'
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>yvueBluWlIZONWqmCorDxFildoWLxd
```

**XSL file:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
 <xsl:template name="initial-template">
      <!--<xsl:value-of select="$input"/>-->
 <!--   <xsl:variable name="json" select="unparsed-text($input)"/>-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($input)"/>
    <!--  <xsl:value-of select="$json"/>-->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do I have to use professional or EE edition to get this working?
I have java application that produces same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `json-to-xml()` function produces an XML node tree. You are applying templates to the root of that tree, but you do not have any template rules to process these nodes. Therefore the default template rules are used; the default template rules skip element and attribute nodes and output only the text nodes. Add `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`, or simply use `xsl:copy-of` (or `xsl:sequence`) in place of `xsl:apply-templates`.